# Copying structure and array

Tags: c

Can you please tell me, how to copy a structure & array (pointer to structure and array) between kernel space and user space, in kernel memory using ioctl interface in C language with OMAP?

Comment: This is not very clear, which might be partially my fault for trying to clean it up. Please avoid overly abbreviating your text, write "you" instead of "u", don't litter periods all over the place, et cetera.

Comment: Is this a Linux specific question? Or does it apply also to MacOSX, and/or to any UNIX?

Answer (score 1):

Read the source for an ioctl that returns a structure from the kernel you're interested in.  TIOCGETA would be a good example, because it returns a structure, and every Unix-ish OS has to implement it.